# installing the MOTODEV core plugins into eclipse "git command" s

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, motodev-studio

I am going through the MOTODEV Core plugins installation [here](http://www.motorola.com/sites/motodev/library/motodev_core_plugins.html)

I get to the step:
- "Use the git clone command to download the MOTODEV Core Plugins source repository into a working copy"

And this is where I get stuck. Where do I input this "git clone" command into Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

You could very easily do the clone from the command line as follows:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/motodev.git
```

and then import the sources from the filesystem into eclipse -- it should pick up your project structure automatically.

Comment: If you're on windows, Start -> CMD.EXE, if you're on a Mac, it would be using /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app and if you're on Linux, fire up an XTerm or Gnome Terminal or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Install "windows git" (http://msysgit.github.com/)

then type that git clone into a command line.

It keeps stopping between 43% and 61% for me though...damned aggravating because git clone doesn't have a continue command (I googled for a while for it and apparently it was a 2009 Google Summer of Code project but was never done)=: